# Uninstall a Windows driver when the hardware is not connected

Tags: windows, hardware, uninstallation, drivers

I am developing a Windows C++ application that drives a motor controller that is  plugged on USB.
This controller relies on Ftdibus drivers and it works fine on my PC.
However, on a test computer it used to work but since I messed up with the Ftdi drivers as soon as I plug the controller, I get a BSoD (mentioning Ftdibus).
I would like to cleanup the drivers, but:

- they do not appear in Windows "uninstall programs"
- I can't right click on the controller in the device manager and chose "uninstall" because I can't plug the controller (BSoD)
- I tried nirsoft [tool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) that has an option to uninstall devices but it won't work

I'm clueless, how could I clean up that mess?

PS: if anyone has documentation regarding how drivers are bound to an USB port number, I would enjoy reading on the subject

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If this is Vista and later, the supported method for deleting a driver package is with pnputil:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550428(v=vs.85).aspx#deleting_a_driver_package_from_the_driver_store

Just deleting the service is sort of a bad idea, that's not the only thing that installing a driver puts in the registry.

I missed the second part of your post about how Windows binds drivers to USB devices. There's a nice description of it here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/10/255047.aspx

If you need more details feel free to contact me (I specialize in Windows drivers for a living :))

Comment: @snoone How do I uninstall and install back again a device driver?

Answer (score 10):

How I do it is one of three ways:

1. Go into Device Manager, select 'view' menu and select the 'Show hidden devices'. Find your device description and select the 'uninstall' menu option. [easy]
2. You can use the Service Control Manager command line '[SC](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sc.mspx?mfr=true)' to delete the device driver from the registry.  You will need to know the installed driver name. [medium]
3. Manually delete the driver setup in the registry.  Using regedit, you can delete the registry entries for the driver.  Drivers registry setup lives under 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services'.  Find the driver name key and delete it. [hard]

Comment: Already tried method #1: device does not show up. Will try #2 and #3. Thanks

Comment: argh! how am i supposed to know what this driver's name is?

Answer (score 0):

I would try [this](https://4sysops.com/archives/free-device-remover-a-powerful-device-manager-alternative/).
It seems like it would work for your case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30543729)